# The type '<>f__AnonymousType1`2[System.String,System.Data.Linq.Binary]' must declare a default (parameterless) constructor

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm getting the exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: The type '<>f__AnonymousType1`2[System.String,System.Data.Linq.Binary]' must declare a default (parameterless) constructor in order to be constructed during mapping.

when I try run

```
await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
```

a very simple command that returns rows from a table that contains a rowversion (`timestamp, not null`) column. Any idea why? Very strange.

EDIT:

It's actually failing when I run

```
return this.Translate<T>(reader);
```

directly afterwards.

Comment: Can you show the code for the anonymous type you're creating?

Comment: @itsme86 See edit

Comment: @itsme86 Sure, it's like from pct in `Context.ProductChangeTrackings select new { pct.SKU, pct.RowVersion };`

Comment: If you are targeting .NET 4.0 or higher, use tuples…

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are trying to translate your reader in the type that does not have default constructor. That means you have defined your own constructor in the type which overrides the default parameterless constructor.

Simple define the parameter less constructor in the Type in which you are trying to translate the reader object and you are done.